# Python reading embed codes, extract urls and write url titles to new csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have multiple embed codes in this csv file and I wanted to read  the urls and copy their title tags to a new csv.

I am able to do it, however with the format is a bit unexpected.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('test.csv','r') as f:
    csv_raw = f.read()

    with open('newtest.csv','w') as ff:
        cw = csv.writer(ff)

        split_csv=csv_raw.split('\n')
        #split_csv.remove('')
        separator=","

        for each in split_csv:
            url_row_index=0
            url = each.split(separator)[url_row_index]
            url_delete = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' #delete extra texts
            url_delete2 = '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' #delete extra texts
            url2 = url.replace(url_delete,'')
            url3 = url2.replace(url_delete2,'')

            html=requests.get(url3).content
            soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
            namelist = soup.title.string
            word_delete = 'Video ' #delete extra wordings - Video
            word_delete2 = '.mp4 (cloned)' #delete extra wordings - .mp4 (cloned)
            namelist2 = namelist.replace(word_delete,'')
            namelist3 = namelist2.replace(word_delete2,'')

            print(namelist3)
            cw.writerow(namelist3)
#So say in the original csv file, these are the embed codes
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.fembed.com/v/2222222" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.fembed.com/v/1111111" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The title tags are

Video 111helloworld111.mp4 (cloned)

Video 222helloworld222.mp4 (cloned)

After running the code I'll be able to print out these

111helloworld111

222helloworld222

And I'd expect to see them at the new csv file

However, in the new csv file it'll be like this

1,1,1,h,e,l,l,o,w,o,r,l,d,1,1,1

2,2,2,h,e,l,l,o,w,o,r,l,d,2,2,2

Something is wrong with my code but I just don't know what is it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `writerow` expects an iterable, which strings are. you can simply write `cw.writerow([namelist3])` so that what you write is the list containing just that string. But i'm not sure why you need csv for that, if you only write 1 string per line?

Comment: Hi, it's really because i would want to scrap more information later on and added them to the new csv.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm still a bit confused with writerow. 
I was following this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5uM4VKywbA&t=417s

when he's writing to a csv, he simply wrote writerow(line). 
So when do I need to add in the [] within writerow() ?

Comment: because in that case, line comes from reading a line of csv, which is a list, whereas your content is a single string. One slightly confusing thing in python is that for most intents and purposes, strings can be seen as lists of characters, which is what shows in your example

Answer (score 0):

sorted. Thanks to @njzk2. 
It's really me misunderstanding python. 
In this case, I should be treating the output from namelist3 as a list, instead of a string,as @njzk2 pointed out in his reply.

So the answer to my question is to simply add [] to my code, which is cw.writerow([namelist3])